# Do you know any free social network software?

Tags: java, social-networking

I am going to start a project in which I want to develop a private social network that will be accessed by mobile devices. To do that, I will use a framework called [Mobilis](http://mobilisplatform.sourceforge.net/) which helps in the development of services for real time collaboration.
This service has a server which communicates to with an arbitrary underlying social network server. 
I have searched for social networks and found many different products and I can't test all of them. I would like to know if you had experience with any of these products, I am looking for a service with these properties:

1. Free (no need to pay for it)
2. API to make remote calls from a Java server
3. It would be very nice if I didn't need to deploy on my own server, if I could use theirs

The features I need from the service are the basic ones:

1. Add someone to your "friends"
2. Send message
3. Some "group" our "forum" like interaction

So, did you do something similar to it and could advice what to use or what not to use?

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: What do you mean by "free"? Are you looking for an open source social networking platform you can use/modify?

Comment: By free I mean that it has no cost. I want to use the social networking platform, but it is unlikely I will modify it. I just edited the question to make clear what "free" means :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out something like [Eureka Streams](http://www.eurekastreams.org/)? I don't know all of its capabilities, but it is free (and [open source](https://github.com/lmco/eurekastreams)), and, from the website, it looks like it has everything you're looking for. (The only thing I am unsure about is the API to make remote calls from a Java server.)

Comment: Thanks, just took a look at it :) I will use this one: http://noosfero.org/Site :)